# Problems with ajax post

Tags: java, ajax, post

Hi i've a simple registration form on my web application on eclipse.
And i make this little script for control on duplicate username.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#idBtnRegister').click(function(){

                username = $('#idUsername').val();

                CCService.findUsername(username,{
                    callback: function(find) {
                        if(find == true) {

                            $('#idUsername').popover({ html: true, content: 'username already exist', placement: 'right' });
                            $('#idUsername').popover('show');
                        }



                        else {
                            url = '<%= CCGestioneConstants.CONTEXT_PATH %>' + '/registered'; 

                            var params = {};
                            params["username"] = $('#idUsername').val();
                            params["name"] = $('#idName').val();
                            params["surname"] = $('#idSurname').val();
                            params["password"] = $('#idPassword').val();
                            params["email"] = $('#idEmail').val();

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: params,
                                url: url,
                                async: false,
                                cache: false,
                            });

                        }
                    },
                    async: false
                });

            }); 

        });

</script>
```

CCService.findUsername it's a DWR call:

```
public boolean findUsername(String username) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
        boolean find = userDao.findUserByUsername(username);

        return find;
    }
```

The url should invoke the servlet mapped on /registerd

```
url = '<%= CCGestioneConstants.CONTEXT_PATH %>' + '/registered';
```

Actually all works, the user will be added on the db if the username don't already exists, but in the servlet, the command:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("html/pages/registered.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

don't redirect on the jsp but i'm still on the registration page.

WHY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calls are in Ajax. You'd need to add a handler on the Ajax response and redirect the browser to your page (registered.jps), using a window.location = url.

The forward in your servlet may work, but as you call the servlet in Ajax it won't have any effect on the content of your web page.